# Is it possible to get a hand on api key configured for a api gateway inside the backend lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to log the api key which is used to invoke the api gateway url which in turn calls the backend lambda. I have configured api gateway with a couple of api keys. What I need now is to log api key from inside of a lambda function.

Is there a way api key id or api key name  can be made visible to he lambda function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a chalice app. So I was able to solve this using `app.current_request.to_dict()`
It has having all the data I needed.

Refer this for more info: [chalice rest api](https://aws.github.io/chalice/tutorials/basicrestapi.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you **can't get the name directly** from the request object. But you can do a reverse lookup through [get_api_keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_keys). So you could have to obtain the list of the api keys in your lambda using the `get_api_keys`, and iterate over them till you find a match.

Depending on your usage pattern and number of keys, such lookup can be time consuming and not desired. Thus you can also store key-id and the corresponding key name in, e.g. **DynamoDb**. This will allow for efficient lookup of the key names based on the key id.

Comment: how do I get hands at api key id ?